# Возможно ли в .Net RichTextBox отключить "перенос по словам" "line wrap"?

Tags: .net, richtextbox, перенос-слов

Смотрел все аттрибуты и функции, такого нет.
Решение единственное видимое, установить самому RichTextBox ширину такую которая заберёт полосу прокрутки вертикальную справа.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Класс наследуемый №5/5, это TextBoxBase. у него есть структура с именем WordWrap, определенными set get (видимо методами op_коды оператаров).